# How do I redirect from a custom Struts RequestProcessor class?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, struts

I am developing a Struts application. I need allow only `POST` method requests to call the action class.

To do this I have written custom `RequestProcess` class and overridden `processPreprocess` method:

```
@Override
protected boolean processPreprocess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    if("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
        return true;
    }else
        return false;
}
```

If the request method is `GET` I want to redirect to the `index.jsp` page.

I am not sure what the best way to manage this redirect is?

Comment: You need to disable GET for all your Actions, or only for a particular one?

Comment: Also, which version of Struts are you using. Please provide more info so we can help you.

Comment: I am using Struts 1.3. Yes I want to call Action.execute() method for only POST requests

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can write your custom error codes in response from your overrided method e.g
response.getWriter().write("INVALID REQUEST").
Convert this as per your project configuration. Based on these custom error codes, you can redirect to whatever page you like from client side i.e from callback methods of the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect on `GET` request then you should do something like

```
@Override
protected boolean processPreprocess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    if("GET".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())){
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/index.jsp");
        return false;
    }else
        return super.processPreprocess(request, response);
}
```